# Azure B2C LogoutRequest Signing

Tags: azure, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I use Azure AD B2C as a SAML IDP. It's works well expect SingleLogout flow.
When LogoutRequest from B2C comes to (my app) ITfoxtec it crashes because this request is not signed.
I can't force Azure AD B2C to sign its' requests as well as I can't skip signing verification for ITfoxtec. Could you help to fix it ?

Best regards,
Alexandr Zolotarev

Answer (score 0):

The SAML 2.0 standard require both the LogoutRequest and the LogoutResponse to be signed. The [ITfoxtec Identity SAML package](https://www.itfoxtec.com/identitysaml2) follows the SAML 2.0 standard and it is therefore not possible to disable the signature check.

If you like you could [down load the code](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2) and change it to not validate the signature.